# Is the CollectionBase class still supported?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, collectionbase

I want to create a class that inherits from [`CollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx), but it seems that it does not support LINQ extensions!

Is it still supported? Or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Why not simply implement IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @Tejs: Because I have some validation functionality and I would encapsulate them.

Comment: CollectionBase seems old-fashioned, pre-generics. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: Sounds to me like simply inheriting List<T> and then adding your own validation methods would be the quickest way to me =/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is still *supported*, but it is obsolete. You should always prefer to use the collections defined in the [`System.Collections.Generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) or the [`System.Collections.ObjectModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel.aspx) namespaces, instead.

You can inherit from one of the generic collections to create your own custom, strongly-typed collection, as well. And it will have full support for LINQ, since they already implement `IEnumerable<T>`.
Either [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) are good options for your case.

Avoid the non-generic collections like `CollectionBase`, `ArrayList`, and `HashTable` if at all possible. There is a performance penalty to using them, and they offer few advantages (if any!) over the generic versions that were introduced in more recent versions of the framework.

Comment: Comment by [qtg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7368376/qtg) incorrectly passed as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669778/5292302) *"Can you please provide any Link regarding obsolete on Official MSDN?"*

Comment: Source for comment on obsolete (though it's a recommendation): "We don't recommend that you use the CollectionBase class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic Collection<T> class." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.collectionbase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score 4):

[Linq extensions are written for `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) (Generic) and *CollectionBase* (Non-generic) does not inherit from it. That is why you are not able to use Linq on it.

Use [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) instead.