# Declaring a CollectionBase to be of a specific type? VB2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to declare a CollectionBase to be of a certain object type? So say I want to create a CollectionBase that accepts object type of car

```
Public Class carCollection
    Inherits CollectionBase
```

In my main program, say I declare and assign a car to the collection

```
Dim myCarCollection As New carCollection
Dim myCar As car = New car()
myCarCollection.Add(myCar);
```

When I try this, Compiler tells me it disallows late binding:

```
myCarCollection(0).Drive()
```

I have to convert first so it's early bound in order to fix it:

```
(CType(myCarCollection(0),car).Drive()
```

Is there a way to just declare carCollection to be a CollectionBase of type car first, so I don't have to convert the type every time I want to make a call?

Turning option restrict off is a workaround too but I just feel like there should be a way to declare what type of object your collectionBase is going to hold.

Comment: Might want to read through this question and it's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704776/is-the-collectionbase-class-still-supported

Comment: A simple `List(Of Car)` would do.