# How can LINQ actions be performed on a CollectionBase?

Tags: c#, linq, collectionbase

I am coding a C# forms application and I have the following collection for a PropertyGrid control:

```
public class CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunctionCollection : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public void Add(CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunction obj)
    {
        this.List.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Remove(CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunction obj)
    {
        this.List.Remove(obj);
    }

    public CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunction this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunction)this.List[index];
        }
    }

    public String GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public String GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type. Returns properties with certain
    /// attributes. this restriction is not implemented here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Create a collection object to hold property descriptors
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pds = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

        // Iterate the list of employees
        for (int i = 0; i < this.List.Count; i++)
        {
            // Create a property descriptor for the employee item and add to the property descriptor collection
            CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunctionCollectionPropertyDescriptor pd = new CustomWebpageJavaScriptFunctionCollectionPropertyDescriptor(this, i);
            pds.Add(pd);
        }
        // return the property descriptor collection
        return pds;
    }
}
```

How is the best way to perform LINQ queries on the above collection?

For example, how can I perform a .Where() action on the contents of the CollectionBase List?

Comment: LINQ requires generic enumerables, `CollectionBase` is non-generic. Try doing `OfType<object>()` first, then you can use LINQ on the `IEnumerable<object>` instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the CollectionBase class still supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704776/is-the-collectionbase-class-still-supported)

Comment: @odyss-jii: Thank you a lot. That is exactly what I needed. If you post an answer, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ requires generic enumerables, `CollectionBase` is non-generic. Try doing `OfType<object>()` first, then you can use LINQ on the `IEnumerable<object>` instance.

Edit: As noted in the comments, you can also use `Cast<object>()`. The difference between the two methods is that `OfType` will include elements which can be cast to the specified type in the enumeration and skip the rest, whilst `Cast` requires that all elements can be cast to the type (otherwise an exception is thrown). `Cast` is faster, since it skips the check and does the cast straight away.

`Cast` iterator source:

```
foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
```

`OfType` iterator source:

```
foreach (object obj in source) {
    if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Comment: @w.b: Yeah, Cast is faster if casting to `object` anyway, and list contains no null elements, no need for additional check.

Comment: On second thought, null is "castable" to reference types.